# Python allow-origin with multiple subdomains

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, netlify

I deploy my web app with Netifly.

It has preview environment that looks this way:

```
"randomonstring33712638126--domaincom.netlify.app"
```

And I have a python function at Google Cloud, that I want to secure with `allow-origin`. How can I allow origin for all domains that ends with `--domaincom.netlify.app`?

I tried this, but seems like it's not working:

```
ALLOW_ORIGIN = 'https://domain[dot]com/, https://*--domaincom.netlify.app/'
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid allowing subdomains isn't something you can do with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Have a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#directives): the `Allow-Origin` can accept

- the wildcard, `*` (any origin)
- a specified origin, e.g. `https://example.app`
- or `null`

For limiting multiple domains it says

> Limiting the possible `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` values to a set of
> allowed origins requires code on the server side to check the value of
> the Origin request header, compare that to a list of allowed origins,
> and then if the Origin value is in the list, set the
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value to the same value as the Origin
> value.